# How to fetch values from json array object without using object key name javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

[Json Array Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJfy0.png)

Through Ajax I will get dynamic data which is not constant or similar data based on query data will change. But I want to display charts so I used chartjs where I need to pass array data. So I tried below code but whenever data changes that code will break.

I cannot paste complete JSON file so after parsing it looks like this
[{"brand":"DUNKIN' DONUTS KEURIG","volume":1.9,"value":571757},{"brand":"MC CAFE","volume":1.1,"value":265096}];

Comment: Kindly click the Json Array Object link to see the code. Thanks

Comment: please copy paste your code into the question itself

Comment: Please add the actual code. Noone's going to retype your code all over just to see the issues. And once imgur stops working, this question becomes useless for others without any code to look at.

Comment: var jsondata = [{"brand":"DUNKIN' DONUTS KEURIG","volume":1.9,"value":571757},{"brand":"MC CAFE","volume":1.1,"value":265096}];

Comment: [Pictures of code are unhelpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and you seem to be [confusing JSON and JavaScript](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: @KarthikGowda — Click *edit* and put a [mcve] *in the question*, don't drop lumps of code into a comment.

Comment: You have an array of objects, there is no JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Object.keys and specify the position number to get that value

```
var valueOne =[];
var valueTwo = [];
jsonData.forEach(function(e){
   valueOne.push(e[Object.keys(e)[1]]);
   valueTwo.push(e[Object.keys(e)[2]]);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you're trying to do is conditionally populate an array based the data you are receiving. One solution might be for you to use a variable who's value is based on whether the `value` or `price` property exist on the object. For example, in your forEach loop:

```
const valueOne = [];

jsonData.forEach((e) => {
  const val = typeof e.value !== undefined ? e.value : e.average;
  valueOne.push(val);
})
```

Comment: I need two arrays var valueone = []; and var valuetwo = []; in this condition if I want to push volume in one array and value in another array.

Comment: In that case you could always simply right a conditional statement.

If (e.volume !== undefined) valueOne.push(e.volume)
if (e.value !== undefined) valueTwo.push(e.value)

Answer (score 1):

In your jsonData.forEach loop you can test existence of element by using something like:

```
if (e['volume']===undefined) {
    valueone.push(e.price);
} else {
    valueone.push(e.volume);
}
```

And similar for valuetwo...

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object with the keys of your first array element, and values corresponding to the arrays you are after:

```js
var data = [{"brand":"DUNKIN' DONUTS KEURIG","volume":1.9,"value":571757},{"brand":"MC CAFE","volume":1.1,"value":265096}];

var splitArrays = Object.keys(data[0]).reduce((o, e) => {
  o[e] = data.map(el => el[e]);
  return o;
}, {});
// show the whole object 
console.log(splitArrays);

// show the individual arrays
console.log("brand");
console.log(splitArrays.brand);

console.log("volume");
console.log(splitArrays.volume);
// etc
```